# Apt package not reflected in Pyenv

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu

I have installed [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) on Ubuntu 12.04. It has default python version 2.7.3. I have installed 2.7.5 in dir `abc` in `/home/test/abc`. I have installed `python-uno` using `apt-get`.

If I do `import uno` under `/home` it imports uno package.

```
>>> import uno
>>> uno.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uno.pyc'
```

But when I try to import it under `abc` it gives error,

```
>>> import uno
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named uno
```

How to handle this error?

Comment: Perhaps the version changes depending on directory. For each of `/home` and `abc`, what is the result of `import sys; print sys.version`?

Comment: Inside `home` it is `2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39)
[GCC 4.6.3]` and under `abc` it is `2.7.5 (default, Nov 29 2013, 11:01:40) [GCC 4.6.3]`. The Pyenv module is used to have different python version in same system. My problem is how to tell python 2.7.5 that `uno` module is installed.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior of pyenv. One of the solution is to create virtual environment (virtualenv) inside pyenv. For this requirement [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv) is present.

But this is not complete solution for this scenario. UNO files are not imported during creation of virtualenv. So we have to manually copy `uno.py` and `unohelper.py` from system location to pyenv installtion.

Copying `uno.py` and `unohelper.py` to pyenv python site-packages solved my problem.